# Unable to import library project and sample given for tooltip in eclipse for android

Tags: android, eclipse, tooltip

in my application I want to add tooltip to the image button. So, after searching on google I found the solution on link given below:-

```
https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips
```

But after downloading the project I am not able to import it into eclipse. Will anybody please tell me why it's happening? 
Sometimes it get imported but no src folder found or some contents are missing.
Please tell what should I do so I can import their lib and sample successfully, or tell me something about tooltip in android. 
Any tutorial will be good idea.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score -1):

SuperToolTips now uses the gradle build structure. If you want to use this project in Eclipse, you should make the necessary changes.
Add the following to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.nhaarman.supertooltips:library:3.0.+'
```

}

In Eclipse, just import the library as an Android library project.

- Project > Clean to generate the binaries you need, like R.java, etc.
- Then, just add SuperToolTips as a dependency to your existing project and you're good to go!

click on this ->
[Steps to use supertooltips in Eclipse](http://nhaarman.github.io/supertooltips/)